# CRC32 checksum in Python with hex input

Tags: python, string, hex, checksum, crc32

I'm wanting to calculate the CRC32 checksum of a string of hex values in python. I found zlib.crc32(data) and binascii.crc32(data), but all the examples I found using these functions have 'data' as a string ('hello' for example). I want to pass hex values in as data and find the checksum. I've tried setting data as a hex value (0x18329a7e for example) and I get a TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int. The function evaluates when I make the hex value a string ('0x18329a7e' for example), but I don't think it's evaluating the correct checksum. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you mean by "pass hex values in"? Do you realize that hexadecimal is just a numeric representation for humans, and that CRC32 applies to binary data? It is not clear what exactly you want to do: to calculate the CRC32 of a string containing hex characters, or of some binary data that happens to be represented as hexadecimal values somewhere in your software.

Comment: I want to calculate the CRC32 of some binary data that happens to be represented as hexadecimal values somewhere in my software.

Comment: Then Andrew's answer does it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`binascii.a2b_hex()`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex):

```
>>> binascii.crc32(binascii.a2b_hex('18329a7e'))
-1357533383
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. The results match up with an online crc calculator (http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html).

I didn't specify in the initial question, but I'm also looking for the output to be a string of 8 hex values. The following code formats the output correctly if anyone's wondering:

'%08X' % (binascii.crc32(binascii.a2b_hex('18329a7e')) & 0xffffffff)

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import struct,binascii
>>> ncrc = lambda numVal: binascii.crc32(struct.pack('!I', numVal))
>>> ncrc(0x18329a7e)
-1357533383
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the list of hex values to a string:

```
t = ['\x18', '\x32', '\x9a', '\x7e']
chksum = binascii.crc32(str(t))
```

Comment: I doubt he wants to convert a list to a string like this. Replacing your second line with binascii.crc32(''.join(t)) gives the same result as phihag's answer.